# WordPress: How to create 'The Loop' in a page?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a Specialized Page Template, where I want to display list of posts, like the blog (home page). Is it possible to create 'The Loop' in that page?

I think I can use `get_posts()` to create the loop. Is there any better method?

Comment: Yes, try to copy from the main loop.

Comment: Also check [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to query WordPress.

```
<?php $all_posts = get_posts(); ?>
```

Then instead of the while loop

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

use the following code:

```
<?php foreach ( $all_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  ?>
```

And it will work like `The Loop`.

If anyone knows a better way, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the WordPress Codex. It's very useful.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Yes, I did. See my own answer below. Thank you.